# Google Analytics Data Api (GA4) Get Transccation with depended infromation

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, magento2, php-7.4

we are moved to GA4 and now i'm trying to get data from GA4, but i cant move some part of code

```
                $filters = ['dimensions' => 'ga:transactionId,ga:deviceCategory,ga:channelGrouping'];

                if (is_array($orderIds)) {
                    $orderCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
                    $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $orderIds]);

                    $startDate = $this->getStartDateFilter($orderCollection);
                    $filters = $this->getMetricsFilter($orderCollection);
                }

                $data = $this->_analytics->data_ga->get(
                    'ga:' . $profileId,
                    $startDate,
                    'today',
                    'ga:transactions',
                    $filters
                );
```

What i have done now

```
 * Set our property ID
 */
$propertyId = 'XXXXXX';

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$request = (new RunReportRequest())
    ->setProperty('properties/' . $propertyId)
    ->setDateRanges([
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2023-10-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ])
    ->setDimensionFilter(new FilterExpression())
    ->setDimensions([
            new Dimension([
                'name' => 'transactionId',
            ]),
            new Dimension([
                'name' => 'deviceCategory',
            ]),
            new Dimension([
                'name' => 'sessionDefaultChannelGrouping',
            ])
    ]);
$response = $client->runReport($request);
```

Maybe somebody know what i should do to get the same information ?

Rewrite previous code and check GA4 documentation